# How to Download xls file stored in Ir_attachment or open an xls file saved in local?

Tags: download, odoo, xls

I use odoo8 with old api for the moment.
I have created an xls file and stored it in ir_attachment.
Now i need to download it so the client user can choose to download it in a selected local location or ope the xls file using microsoft excel or any app which can open xls file.
I can see Odoo is using saveas and saveas_ajax, but i'm not able to make that work (not much details on passing data to those methods).
So the question is:

- List item
  how to download the xls file in a location that needs to be chosen by the web user?

or how to write the xls file locally to client side in a location that is chosen by the client user?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look to the `knowledge` and `document` modules

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. The solution in knowledge is just an add of more attachments to the same ir.attachment but the download is also a link. What i need is to download it from python method. So if there is a solution to call a method and download the xls file, plase help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found.

After creating the record in ir.attachment you can return:

```
new_attach = attachment_obj.create(cr, uid, attachment_data)

return {

'type' : 'ir.actions.act_url',

'url': '/web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&    filename_field=name&id=%s' % ( new_attach, ),

'target': 'self',

}
```

Where new_attach is the id of the new created record in ir.attachment.

The result is the open/save file windows dialog.

Many thanks!